# Get all links, URLs an URIs from HTML

Tags: python, regex

I want to get **all the types of links, URLs and URIs** from the html. Basically, anything that i can put on Chrome's search bar and that leads me to another page/download an archive.

By now, i have this code, but this code only gets links from the `href`, and only from `a` tags, but i want literally every type of link, from `src`, `source`, `<source>`, and even links that came "fused" in the html.

```py
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(url):
    data = rq.get(url).content.decode()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser').find_all('a')

    links = [link.get('href') for link in soup]
    return links

link = input('Enter URL: ')
all_links = get_links(link)
print(all_links)
```

Any idea how to make it? I can only thing in using RegEx, but it would be a nightmare.

**Edit1:**
Okay... 
I want every type of link, static files, mp4 links, even if is not an actually usable page.
Being `*` an url that i want:

```
<script src="*" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="*"/>
<link rel="icon" href="*" sizes="32x32"/>
<form method="post" action="*">
<img src="*">
<div data-playerurl="*"></div>
```

Edit2: I found something that does the work

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = '".*?//(.*?)"'
>>> re.search(pat, '*some html here*"//something.com/path1/path2"*some html here too*').group(1)
'something.com/path1/path2'

>>> re.search(pat, '*some html here*"https://something.com/path1/path2"*some html here too*').group(1)
'something.com/path1/path2'
```

But it still don't get from places like `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" crossorigin="use-credentials">`

Comment: @CinCout i'm using BeautifulSoup4 4.9.3, the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i found an Regex pattern:

```py
import re

def formatUrl(url):
    if not re.match('(?:http|ftp|https)://', url):
        return f'http://{url}'
    return url

regex_url_pattern = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»""‘’]))"

urls = [formatUrl(x[0]) for x in re.findall(regex_url_pattern, html)]
```

Works well, but sometimes it gives the url+arguments from the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple bfs based webcrawler

Use depth = 1 If you need all the links from only that one specific html

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import deque

visited = set(["URL"])
dq = deque([["URL", "", 0]])
max_depth = 3

while dq:
    base, path, depth = dq.popleft()
                  

    if depth < max_depth:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base + path).text, "html.parser")

            for link in soup.find_all("a"):
                href = link.get("href")

                if href not in visited:
                    visited.add(href)
                    print("  " * depth + f"at depth {depth}: {href}")

                    if href.startswith("http"):
                        dq.append([href, "", depth + 1])
                    else:
                        dq.append([base, href, depth + 1])
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: But it still only gets URLs from `a` tags, right? As i said, i want any and all url, even if is from the page's css